# Php Multi Arraylist Last Element

Tags: php, arraylist

I am trying to create a Json+ld schema from my data but i have a problem on this arraylist.

I need to know last element on array list

```
    foreach ($malzemeler as $val):
    echo 'ana'.$fkey.'</br>';
    foreach($val['malzemeler'] as $val):
        echo $val.', ';
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

This code helps me to get all values which i need but i must add "," to them till last element

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Malzemeler
            [malzemeler] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1 su bardağı kırmızı mercimek
                    [1] => 1 adet soğan
                    [2] => 1 yemek kaşığı un
                    [3] => 1 adet havuç
                    [4] => yarım yemek kaşığı biber ya da domates salçası (rengi kırmızı olsun isterseniz artırabilir ya da hiç kullanmayabilirsiniz)
                    [5] => Tuz
                    [6] => 1 çay kaşığı karabiber
                    [7] => yarım çay kaşığı kimyon (isteğe bağlı)
                    [8] => 1 litre su
                    [9] => 2 yemek kaşığı sıvı yağ
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Sosu için
            [malzemeler] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2 yemek kaşığı tereyağı
                    [1] => 1 tatlı kaşığı kırmızı toz biber
                )

        )

)


"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"

foreach ($malzemeler as $key => $val):
  $last_key = end(array_keys($malzemeler));
  if ($key == $last_key):
    echo implode(', ',$val['malzemeler']).'"'.PHP_EOL;
  else:
    foreach ($val['malzemeler'] as $val):
      echo '"'.$val.'", '.PHP_EOL;
    endforeach;
  endif;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Check out json_encode (php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: I tried it but i need only elements under [malzemeler] in each array and need to get them together

Comment: I'd just send the extra data and sort it out later.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Now that I can see what you were trying to accomplish:

```
for($i = 0; $i  < count($malzemeler) - 1; $i++)
  echo '"' . implode('", "',$malzemeler[$i]) . '", ' . PHP_EOL;
echo '"' . implode('", "',$malzemeler[$i]) . '"' . PHP_EOL;
```

**Old answer**:

Instead of looping through each element of `$malzemeler`, use [`implode()`](https://secure.php.net/implode) which will concatenate all the elements of an array together for you, putting whatever string you pass between them.

```
foreach ($arr as $val)
  echo 'ana'. $fkey.'<br/>'.implode(', ', $val['malzemeler']);
```

You also probably shouldn't use the same variable names in a `foreach` loop like you are doing.*

*citation needed

Comment: Thanks for your effort,
It is removing "," from each array

This shall got all elements under [malzemeler] then puts ","

Comment: @ÖzgürKalyoncu if you could explain again what you need I'll try and write you an answer that helps.

Comment: values under [malzemeler] shall be merged than echo all of them without last element has ","

Comment: Values under of malzemeler will be merged together across all elements? If you add what the output should be, based on the example input you already provided, that would really help

Comment: "1","2","3","4","5",6","7" that is result example i am so close with your help
` <?php foreach ($malzemeler as $key => $val): $last_key = end(array_keys($malzemeler));
    if ($key == $last_key):
        echo implode(', ', $val['malzemeler']).'"'.PHP_EOL;
    else:
        foreach ($val['malzemeler'] as $val):
            echo '"'.$val.'", '.PHP_EOL;
        endforeach;
    endif;
endforeach;
?> `

Answer (score 0):

This is answer but it seems a bit spagetti sorry for that and thank you @Terminus for help

```
<?php foreach ($malzemeler as $key => $val): $last_key = end(array_keys($malzemeler));
        if ($key == $last_key):
            echo '"';
            echo implode(', ', $val['malzemeler']).'"'.PHP_EOL;
        else:
            foreach ($val['malzemeler'] as $val):
                echo '"'.$val.'", '.PHP_EOL;
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endforeach;
    ?>
```